# Restoring notification after screen orientation change

Tags: android, notifications, bundle

```
Intent intent_1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            taskStackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
            taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent_1);
            pendingIntent_1 = taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(EBC_ID,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.Text))
                    .setContentText(time)
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent_1)
                    .build();
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

I didn't find anything similar so I decided to ask.
After click start button the notification is displayed, now if I press stop button to disable it calling:
`notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);`
it is ok. But when I change screen orientation the:  notificationManager and notification is null. So the stop button doesn't work, notification is displayed all the time.
How can I store reference to them?
I tried to save it via Bundle object, but it required simple object (string, int), I can't put notification object.
Also tried sharedpreferences and parcelable method but it didn't work, they need (String, int) too.
Also tried something like this:

```
String noti1 = String.valueOf(notification); 
String noti2 = String.valueOf(notificationManager);
```

Then in onSaveInstanceState method()  I am able to pass it:

```
savedInstanceState.putString("notification1", noti1);
savedInstanceState.putString("notification2", noti2);
```

But restoring it like:
`notification = savedInstanceState.getString("notification1");`
Is not allowed. Notification object diffrent than String object.
So how can I get reference to my notification object? (after application is destroyed)
Should I restore only notification object or notificationManager and TaskStackBuilder too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You dont need to go through saving notification.You can always access the notification using its notificationId.**

You can always clear/stop the notification by its using notificationId like that.

```
notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
```

**UPDATE**

*(Answer to crash , Null notificationManager )*

Declare a notificationManager in your Activity like that.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    NotificationManager notificationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}
```

Always initialize NotificationManager in OnCreate Method.

**This way Your NotificationManager will never be null upon screen rotation.**

Comment: Unfortunately. After change screen orientation I have error:

`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.alarmclock, PID: 6016
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.NotificationManager.cancel(int)' on a null object reference
`

Comment: For some reason your NotificationManager is null. I update my answer

Comment: I missed initialization in OnCreate method that was main reason of having the null notificationManager. Now is working perfectly. Thanks. 
By the way I have some question. I always should initialization object like that in onCreate method. For example: notificationManagers, AlarmManagers or AudioService?
I mean those object which are geting acces to the system managment service using `.getSystemService`  command.

Comment: Exactly , in oncreate method

Comment: After that, I found one more problem, I moved `alarmmanager = (AManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);` to OnCreate method but after changed orientation and use stop button can't disable my pendingintent.
I did it like `pendingIntent = PI.getBroadcast(this, ABC_ID, intent, PIt.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);` At start initalized it as `public static final int ABC_ID = 200` After changed orientation and press stop button I try cancel it like `alarmmanager.cancel(PI)` I get error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: cancel() called with a null PendingIntent`
So how can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: You should call stopnotification using notificationid instead of pending intent

Comment: (EDIT) NOTIFICATION IN TITTLE WORKS GOOD
  

No no no. With my notification is everything all right. The problem is with the Alarm. 
`Intent intent = new Intent(this, Alarm_Receiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ABC_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);`
This code start my BroadcastRecevier in some time (get it from timePicker). The problem is when I want cancel this PendingIntent after change orientation screen beacuse it is null.